# Cisco VPN Client automatic login

Tags: authentication, client, vpn, cisco

I need to automate the login process of a Cisco VPN Client version 5.0.07.0440.
I've tried using a command line like this but there is something wrong:

```
vpnclient.exe connect MyVPNConnection user username pwd password
```

This starts the connection but then a User Authentication dialog is shown, asking for username, password and domain. Username and password are already filled, domain is not necessary.

To continue I must press the OK button.

Is there a way to not show the dialog and automatically login into the vpn?

Comment: StackOverflow is mostly programming... you'll probably be better off asking this in some other StackExchange site, like ServerFault.

Comment: Well, indeed I need to do that in c# or delphi, so I think to be in the right place. My bad to not specify it in the main post.

Answer (score 6):

Run `vpnclient.exe /?`:

[image]
That way just run

`vpnclient.exe connect MyVPNConnection -s < file.txt`

**file.txt**

```
username
password
```

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to use the `vpncli.exe` command line approach with the `-s` switch.
It works from command line or script. If you were looking for a solution in `C#`:

```
//file = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"
var file = vpnInfo.ExecutablePath;
var host = vpnInfo.Host;
var profile = vpnInfo.ProfileName;
var user = vpnInfo.User;
var pass = vpnInfo.Password;
var confirm = "y";

var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = file,
        Arguments = string.Format("-s"),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    }
};

proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => stdOut.AppendLine(a.Data);
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, a) => stdOut.AppendLine(a.Data);

//make sure it is not running, otherwise connection will fail
var procFilter = new HashSet<string>() { "vpnui", "vpncli" };
var existingProcs = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => procFilter.Contains(p.ProcessName));
if (existingProcs.Any())
{
    foreach (var p in existingProcs)
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
}

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

//simulate profile file
var simProfile = string.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}"
    , Environment.NewLine
    , string.Format("connect {0}", host)
    , profile
    , user
    , pass
    , confirm
    );

proc.StandardInput.Write(simProfile);
proc.StandardInput.Flush();

//todo: these should be a configurable value
var waitTime = 500; //in ms
var maxWait = 10;

var count = 0;
var output = stdOut.ToString();
while (!output.Contains("state: Connected"))
{
    output = stdOut.ToString();

    if (count > maxWait)
        throw new Exception("Unable to connect to VPN.");

    count++;
    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
}
stdOut.Append("VPN connection established! ...");
```

(This might have extra stuff which is not required for you specific case.)

Answer (score 2):

**Below worked for me Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client:**

1. Try to connect to VPN for the first time using vpncli.exe and note every keystroke i.e *every command, every enter( \n ) you press, username & password you enter.*
2. Copy each command sequentially in `.login_info` file.

**Sample .login_info:**

```
connect unkbown.data-protect.com
\n  
\n
KC23452
\n
```

**Note:** *Replace \n with normal enter, these are the exact steps that I followed while connecting via vpncli.exe. Username and group-name were saved automatically that's the reason the 2nd and 3rd lines are \n ( enter ). Also, the last \n is required.*

3. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
4. Open CMD here
5. `vpncli.exe -s < .login_info`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a BAT script for automatic logon using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 4.10.03104):

```
taskkill -im vpnui.exe -f
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" disconnect
SLEEP 3
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" -s < credential.txt
SLEEP 8
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"
```

The file "credential.txt" must contain three lines:

```
connect <host>
<login>
<password>
```

where `<host>` is IP address or hostname of the host to connect, `<login>` is your login, and `<password>` is your password. The first line `taskkill -im vpnui.exe -f` is nesessary for killing the GUI, because when the GUI is running the login through the command line doesn't work. The last line launches the GUI again after successive logon.

The same script written as a VBS file (suitable for Windows Task Sheduler):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "taskkill -im vpnui.exe -f"

WshShell.Run """%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"" disconnect"

WScript.Sleep 3000

WshShell.Run "cmd /K ""%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"" -s < credential.txt"

WScript.Sleep 8000

WshShell.Run """%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"""
```

Save this script as "login.vbs", and assign running it as an "Action" in the Windows Task Sheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change a little bit to avoid getting stuck in cmd:

```
@echo off
taskkill -im vpnui.exe -f
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" disconnect
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" -s < credential.txt
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"
exit
```